# Firebird SQL cursor repeat last row

Tags: stored-procedures, cursor, firebird, firebird2.5

to begin, sorry for my English. I'm starting with cursors in FirebirdSQL 2.5, writing some stored procedures for a sales register system.
In this case I need to calculate the credit card's taxes that are cashed by the banks in my country from the sales that the system record.  Here is the SP code:

```
create or alter procedure CURSOR_POC
returns (
  ID int,
  PRICE decimal(15,2),
  TAX decimal(15,2))
as
declare variable GO_ON char(1);
declare MY_CURSOR cursor for (
  select CARD.CODE, sum(SALE.PRICE)
  from CARD join SALE on CARD.CODE = SALE.CARD_CODE
  where SALE.SALE_DATE = '14.10.2015'
  group by CARD_CODE);
begin
  open MY_CURSOR;
  GO_ON = 'Y';
  while(GO_ON='Y') do
  begin
    fetch MY_CURSOR into :ID, :PRICE;
    if (row_count = 1) then
    begin
      TAX = PRICE * (select CARD.TAXES from CARD where CARD.CODE = :ID);
      suspend;
    end else GO_ON = 'N';
    end
close MY_CURSOR;
suspend;
end
```

When I run the SP, its execute just fine but always show the last row twice. For instance, if I run the query in a separate file Firebird give me 10 rows, but when I run the SP I got 11 rows.
Any help will be grateful.  In advance, thank you very much.

P.D.: I "translate" the tables and attributes names in order to make it more understable.
P.D.2: the date filter ("dd/mm/yyyy" format) in the definition of the cursor was only define to test de stored procedure.

Comment: Why do you use a cursor in the first place? Unless you are hiding something relevant, you should be able to do that in one single statement

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer. I'm using cursors because I need to totalize all the sales from one credit card, compute the taxes, then process the next one and, finally, show all the results group by credit card. Here, diferents credit cards cash diferent taxes (really, it would be like a agent's commission).  When I tried it only with a single query its totalize all the sales in one row, independently of the credit cards.  I hope to make you understand my case. Again, thank you.

Comment: The problem is solved.  Of course, thanks for your concern @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer myself (a professor help me in a private forum from my University).
The solution was as simple as erase the last "suspend" from the stored procedure.  So that, the code should be

```
(...previous code...)

if (row_count = 1) then
begin
  TAX = PRICE * (select CARD.TAXES from CARD where CARD.CODE = :ID);
  suspend;
end else GO_ON = 'N';
end
close MY_CURSOR;
end
```